# Additionall unneded spaces when puting codeblock inside list in jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll

SOURCE:

```
* **WINDOWS PowerShell DISCLOSURE**

Due to powershell security restrictions issue (setup only once):

* Run PowerShell as admin !!
* Execute this command:

        Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

STACKOVERFLOW (interpreted):

- **WINDOWS PowerShell DISCLOSURE**

Due to powershell security restrictions issue (setup only once):

- Run PowerShell as admin !!
- Execute this command:

  ```
  Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
  ```

JEKYLL (screenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have code block you need a **four** spaces indentation, not six.

Edit: You can enjoy nice code highlight with [highlight tags](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting).